# Is chrome.fileSystem usable inside google Native Client

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

Is it possible to use `chrome.fileSystem` inside `NaCl`?

Thanks

Comment: My guess is "probably not", but seeing that you can access the HTML5 filesystem you could, at worst, copy there to work with it. But I don't know the topic well enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The chrome.fileSystem API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) allows you to access the user's local filesystem via a Chrome App. This requires a user to pick a directory to expose to the App.

This filesystem can be passed to the NaCl module and then used with the standard NaCl [pp::FileSystem](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_stable/cpp/classpp_1_1_file_system) API.

There is an example of this in the NaCl SDK at `examples/tutorial/filesystem_passing`. You can browse the code for it [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/native_client_sdk/src/examples/tutorial/filesystem_passing/).

Here are the important parts:
JavaScript:

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openDirectory'}, function(entry) {
  if (!entry) {
    // The user cancelled the dialog.
    return;
  }

  // Send the filesystem and the directory path to the NaCl module.
  common.naclModule.postMessage({
    filesystem: entry.filesystem,
    fullPath: entry.fullPath
  });
});
```

C++:

```
// Got a message from JavaScript. We're assuming it is a dictionary with
// two elements:
//   {
//     filesystem: <A Filesystem var>,
//     fullPath: <A string>
//   }
pp::VarDictionary var_dict(var_message);
pp::Resource filesystem_resource = var_dict.Get("filesystem").AsResource();
pp::FileSystem filesystem(filesystem_resource);
std::string full_path = var_dict.Get("fullPath").AsString();
std::string save_path = full_path + "/hello_from_nacl.txt";
std::string contents = "Hello, from Native Client!\n";
```

It's important to note that all paths in this FileSystem must be prefixed with full_path. Any other accesses will fail.